# Intro.js Top Positioning Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, position

[image: The bottom of the tip gets cut off even though position is set to top]

I am using Intro.js for a "Tour" of a new product and all of the "Intro Tips" are positioning themselves accordingly except for a certain element that is at the bottom left of the screen. I have tried to set the position to "top" in order to get it to display above the series of icons, however, it is displaying to the right and cutting off the bottom section of the tip which includes the prev and next buttons.

Button triggering the Tour via a popup window:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#welcome').modal('hide'); startIntro();">
```

The div it's on:

```
 <div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small" id="tour6">
```

and the JS that has the issue:

```
{
            element: '#tour6',
            intro: "Navigate here to go back to the home page, to make your 
            screen full-sized, to lock your sidebar so it doesn’t move, or to 
            log out. ",
            position: 'top'
          },
```

Full JS:

```
function startIntro(){
    var intro = introJs();
      intro.setOptions({
        steps: [
          {
            element: '#tour1',
            intro: "Copy",
            position: 'right'
          },
          {
            element: '#tour2',
            intro: "Copy",
            position: 'left'
          },
          {
            element: '#tour3',
            intro: "Copy",
            position: 'left'
          },
          {
            element: '#tour4',
            intro: "Copy",
            position: 'bottom'
          },
          {
            element: '#tour5',
            intro: "Copy",
            position: 'bottom'
          },
          {
            element: '#tour6',
            intro: "Navigate here to go back to the home page, to make your screen full-sized, to lock your sidebar so it doesn’t move, or to log out. ",
            position: 'auto'
          },
          {
            element: '#tour7',
            intro: "Copy"
          }
        ]
      });

      intro.setOption('showProgress', true).setOption('showStepNumbers', false).start();start();
```

Comment: Can you post the js where you start the tour?  Try setting your tooltipPosition to `auto` (can't remember if it does this by default or not).  http://introjs.com/example/auto-position/index.html

Comment: I have tried the 'auto' position and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the js that starts the tour, in this case the startIntro() function.  Can you post that?

Comment: I trigger it via the button code I put in the ticket. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes the actual function that tells intro.js to start the tour.  The button calls startIntro(), so the code in that function.

Comment: I have added the rest of the code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the element id:

use like this->

{
`element: document.getElementById('tour6') as HTMLElement,`
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).